# Confusion about Momentum and Energy and their conservation

Tags: energy, momentum

I've heard that momentum is always transferred macroscopically while kinetic energy of an object can be transferred microscopically, as far as I know

Why? And how does it make sense, how do we know that makes sense

If an object for example slows down to friction, the momentum goes to the entire Earth while the kinetic energy more or less goes to heat and sound etc.. but doesn't the Earth getting some level of motion mean it had some kinetic energy transferred to it?

I'm so confused, and if this post makes an assumption which is incorrect please correct it with whatever is the correct understanding

Answer (score 0):

During an interaction, say a collision, the amount of momentum transferred to an object is not necessarily proportional to the amount of kinetic energy transferred to it.  Consider a head on elastic collision between a moving small mass and a much larger initially stationary mass.  The small mass essentially bounces off the larger one.  It's speed, and thus kinetic energy, ends up only slightly less than before the collision yet the large mass acquires almost twice as much momentum as the small moving mass had initially.